# gluUnProject and finding point on fixed z (OpenGL ES 2.0 android)

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I have a problem with finding clicked point in OpenGL scene. My view matrix is modified everytime when I zoom or rotate screen (I add version with all view parameters here):

```
            final float eyeX = 0.0f;
            final float eyeY = -5.0f;
            final float eyeZ = 25.0f - zoom;

            final float centerX = 0.0f;
            final float centerY = 0.0f;
            final float centerZ = -9.0f;

            final float upX = 0.0f;
            final float upY = 1.0f;
            final float upZ = 0.0f;

            Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, centerX, centerY, centerZ, upX, upY, upZ);
            Matrix.rotateM(viewMatrix, 0, rotateAngle, 0, 0, 1.0f);
```

It works perfect when I'm drawing various models, everything scales and rotates correctly.
But when I try to find clicked point with gluUnProject function, the values seem to be correct (just with inverted y value) only when rotationAngle is zero and zoom is also small. My zoom varies from 1 to 25.
Point finding function looks like this:

```
public PointF getPoint(float touchX, float touchY) {

    int[] view = new int[] { 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight };
    float[] obj = new float[8];
    GLU.gluUnProject(touchX, touchY, -1.0f, viewMatrix, 0,
            projectionMatrix, 0, view, 0, obj, 0);
    GLU.gluUnProject(touchX, touchY, 1.0f, viewMatrix, 0,
            projectionMatrix, 0, view, 0, obj, 4);
    float x1 = obj[0] / obj[3];
    float y1 = obj[1] / obj[3];
    float z1 = obj[2] / obj[3];
    float x2 = obj[4] / obj[7];
    float y2 = obj[5] / obj[7];
    float z2 = obj[6] / obj[7];

    float t = (-10 - z1) / (z1 - z2);
    float x = x1 + t * x1 - t * x2;
    float y = y1 + t * y1 - t * y2;

    return new PointF(x, y);
}
```

I use only view matrix in here, my model matrix is identity here. Is it wrong approach? Also, I try to find only point's x and y coords, z is fixed and equals -10 (that's why -10 is hardcoded).

**EDIT:**

Okay, so it seems, the problem is solved... I modified getPoint function:

```
public PointF getPoint(float touchX, float touchY) {

    float[] almostViewM = new float[16];
    Matrix.setLookAtM(almostViewM, 0, 0.0f, 5.0f, 25.0f - scaleFactor, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            -9.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    Matrix.rotateM(almostViewM, 0, -rotateAngle, 0, 0, 1.0f);       

    int[] view = new int[] { 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight };
    float[] obj = new float[8];
    GLU.gluUnProject(touchX, touchY, -1.0f, almostViewM, 0,
            projectionMatrix, 0, view, 0, obj, 0);
    GLU.gluUnProject(touchX, touchY, 1.0f, almostViewM, 0,
            projectionMatrix, 0, view, 0, obj, 4);
    float x1 = obj[0] / obj[3];
    float y1 = obj[1] / obj[3];
    float z1 = obj[2] / obj[3];
    float x2 = obj[4] / obj[7];
    float y2 = obj[5] / obj[7];
    float z2 = obj[6] / obj[7];

    float t = (-10 - z1) / (z2 - z1);
    float x = x1 + t * x2 - t * x1;
    float y = -(y1 + t * y2 - t * y1);

    return new PointF(x, y);
}
```

I "forged" my view matrix, switching eyeY to -eyeY value and setting rotateAngle to -rotateAngle. Then, I added - to result y value... 
It works now. Still, I have no idea, why it happens. Are y coords and angles inverted for OpenGL 2.0 and GLU? That would explain the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not technically inverted. What is probably happening is that you are using input coordinates from the window system (which are almost always defined with (0,0) as the top-left) and OpenGL tends to make (0,0) the bottom-left if you use a traditional projection matrix.

In the traditional fixed-function OpenGL pipeline, different coordinate handedness conventions apply before and after projection. Coordinates are right-handed to begin with (object/world/view space), but then the projection matrix flips the Z-axis and the result is a left-handed coordinate system (clip/NDC/window space) after vertex transform.

#### What does flipping the Z-axis have to do with the Y-axis in this question?

Well, it turns out that if you modify your projection matrix so that Y=0 is the top of the screen instead of the bottom, you actually introduce another change of handedness. Any time you flip an axis in a coordinate system you produce a mirror image that cannot be duplicated by any combination of rotation or translation; in mathematics, we call this [**chirality**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality).

---

#### There are really two ways to approach this problem:

1. Re-define your projection matrix so that the Y-axis moves in a positive direction as you move from the top to bottom of the window
2. Invert the Y coordinates given to you by the window system

---

#### Option 1

As I mentioned earlier, if you re-define an axis in your projection matrix you will alter the handedness of your post-projected coordinate space. This means rasterization operations that rely on winding direction will all be backwards (e.g. something that used to be wound `GL_CCW` will now be wound `GL_CW`) and if you do not compensate for this by also altering `glFrontFace (...)` then front/back shading, culling, etc. will not work as expected.

#### Option 2

This approach is by far the simpler of the two, but you do have to constantly be aware that the coordinate system used by the window manager and OpenGL are incompatible. You will have to remember to always flip the coordinates given to you for input events before you can use them to reference a point in window space in OpenGL.

---

It all comes down to how often you use coordinates that come directly from the window system (e.g. from input events). OpenGL uses the same convention for texture origin ((0,0) is the bottom-left corner of a texture image) so you may wish to make a mental note of this. I personally would leave OpenGL's coordinate systems the way they are and convert window system coordinates by flipping Y.